# Display inventory for specific product in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display 'out of stock' on the homepage when the product inventory is 0 or less (back-ordered).

This is what I have but it's showing out of stock all the time I'm not sure why.

```
function show_popup_on_home_page() {
    $product_id = '330';
    $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $quantity = $_product->get_stock_quantity();
    if($quantity < 0) {
        echo 'Out of Stock';
    }

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'show_popup_on_home_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
function show_popup_on_home_page() {
$product_id = '330';
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
$manage_stock = $product->get_manage_stock();
$stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();

if($manage_stock != 1){
    if ( $stock_status == 'outofstock' || $stock_status == 'onbackorder'      ){
        echo '<h1>Out of Stock</h1>';
    }
}else{
    if($quantity <= 0) {
        echo '<h1>Out of Stock</h1>';
    }
}
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'show_popup_on_home_page');
```